# Selecting Radiobutton using Jquery in MVCContrib Grid MVC3

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, mvccontrib-grid

I have added a MvcContrib grid in a particular view. In grid, along with the column data, I also have a radiobutton column. I am trying to get selected radiobutton click event but it's not happening as expected. I don't know what's wrong with the implementation. Can you guys have a look and give some suggestion or code snippet to resolve this issue.

```
    <%= Html.Grid(Model.Items)
        .Columns(column =>
                     {
                         column.For(x => x.Name)
                             .Named(Html.OrderBy(null, "DisplayRestaurantsList", "Group", ViewContext.RouteData.Values, "sortBy", "sortDir", true, Model.SortDirection, Model.SortBy, "restaurantname", "Restaurant"));
                         column.For(x => x.Contact.GetDisplayName())
                             .Named(Html.OrderBy(null, "DisplayRestaurantsList", "Restaurant", ViewContext.RouteData.Values, "sortBy", "sortDir", true, Model.SortDirection, Model.SortBy, "administrator", "Administrator"));
                         column.For(x => Html.ActionLink("Remove", "RemoveRestaurant", "Group", new { id = x.ID, GroupID=x.Group.ID }, null))
                            .DoNotEncode();
                         column.For(x => Html.RadioButton("defaultRastaurant",x.ID,(!x.Group.ID.Value.ToString().IsEmptyOrNull() && x.ID==x.Group.DefaultRestaurantID) ? true:false)).Named("default").DoNotEncode();
                     })
        .Attributes(@class => "table-1 gapmb40")
        .Empty("There are no restaurants that match your criteria.")
        .RowStart(row => string.Format("<tr{0}>", row.IsAlternate ? "style=\"background-color:#CCDDCC\"" : ""))

  %>
```

jQuery code to select the radio button click:

```
$("input[type='radio']").click(function () {
               alert("kaustubh");
           });
```

Also tried following one too:

```
 $("input[name='defaultRastaurant']").change(function () {
           alert("kaustubh");               
                          });
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like its a **event delegation** issue. The element is not present in the DOM when the event handler is associated to it..

Try this

```
$("body").on("click"," input[type='radio']" ,function () {
       alert("kaustubh");
 });
```

The body can be replaced by any non static parent in which the radiobuttons are present..